# getting images and tweet url of all the tweets with the call for /home_timeline

Tags: javascript, twitter

When calling twitter to /home_timeline, I'm getting a list of tweets but none of them have the tweet url or any media(images)

How do you get these properties without making a different call for it ?

Comment: What's the API call you're making?  It's hard to help without seeing the code :-)

Comment: @TerenceEden https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

Comment: Are you using `include_entities=true` as mentioned in the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline ?